# foreach appending extra values in each iteration php?

Tags: php, foreach

I am having one array and i want to group by that array with particular id.
e.g $newArr =

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => palanpur
            [city] => palanpur
            [1] => category_1
            [cat_name] => category_1
            [2] => 10000024
            [id] => 10000024
            [3] => 0
            [search_type] => 0
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => palanpur
            [city] => palanpur
            [1] => category_2
            [cat_name] => category_2
            [2] => 10000086
            [id] => 10000086
            [3] => 2
            [search_type] => 2
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => pattukottai
            [city] => pattukottai
            [1] => category_1
            [cat_name] => category_1
            [2] => 10000024
            [id] => 10000024
            [3] => 0
            [search_type] => 0
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [0] => pattukottai
            [city] => pattukottai
            [1] => category_2
            [cat_name] => category_2
            [2] => 10000086
            [id] => 10000086
            [3] => 2
            [search_type] => 2
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [0] => puttur
            [city] => puttur
            [1] => category_1
            [cat_name] => category_1
            [2] => 10000024
            [id] => 10000024
            [3] => 0
            [search_type] => 0
        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [0] => puttur
            [city] => puttur
            [1] => category_2
            [cat_name] => category_2
            [2] => 10000086
            [id] => 10000086
            [3] => 2
            [search_type] => 2
        )

    [6] => Array
        (
            [0] => category_3
            [cat_name] => category_3
            [1] => 10000059
            [id] => 10000059
            [2] => 0
            [search_type] => 0
        )

    [7] => Array
        (
            [0] => category_4
            [cat_name] => category_4
            [1] => 10000060
            [id] => 10000060
            [2] => 0
            [search_type] => 0
        )

)
```

getting above array and i want result like this :(id wise and all city wise inside that id):

```
Array
(
    [10000024] => Array
        (
            [id] => 10000024
            [cat_name] => category_1
            [field] => search_type
            [palanpur] => 0
            [pattukottai] => 0
            [puttur] => 0
        )

    [10000086] => Array
        (
            [id] => 10000086
            [cat_name] => category_2
            [field] => search_type
            [palanpur] => 2
            [pattukottai] => 2
            [puttur] => 2
        )

    [10000059] => Array
        (
            [id] => 10000059
            [cat_name] => category_3
            [field] => search_type
            [palanpur] => 0
            [pattukottai] => 0
            [puttur] => 0
            [universal] => 0
        )

    [10000060] => Array
        (
            [id] => 10000060
            [cat_name] => category_4
            [field] => search_type
            [palanpur] => 0
            [pattukottai] => 0
            [puttur] => 0
            [universal] => 0
        )

)
```

for this i am trying to get data by id in $result but not getting proper result.
first array looping to get new array as i want :
$fields = //user input;

```
foreach($newArr as $k1 =>  $val2){ 
                    $newArray['id'] = $val2['id'];
                    $newArray['cat_name'] = $val2['cat_name'];
                    $newArray['field'] = $fields;
                    if (array_key_exists('city', $val2)){ 
                        $city1 = $val2['city'];
                    } 
                    else { 
                        $city1 = "universal";
                    }
                    $newArray[$city1] = $val2[$fields];
                    $newArray1[] =  $newArray;
                }
```

inside $newArray1 i am getting appended data like this : wrong output :

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 10000024
            [cat_name] => category_1
            [field] => search_type
            [palanpur] => 0
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 10000086
            [cat_name] => category_2
            [field] => search_type
            [palanpur] => 2
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [id] => 10000024
            [cat_name] => category_1
            [field] => search_type
            [palanpur] => 2
            [pattukottai] => 0
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [id] => 10000086
            [cat_name] => category_2
            [field] => search_type
            [palanpur] => 2
            [pattukottai] => 2
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [id] => 10000024
            [cat_name] => category_1
            [field] => search_type
            [palanpur] => 2
            [pattukottai] => 2
            [puttur] => 0
        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [id] => 10000086
            [cat_name] => category_2
            [field] => search_type
            [palanpur] => 2
            [pattukottai] => 2
            [puttur] => 2
        )

    [6] => Array
        (
            [id] => 10000059
            [cat_name] => category_3
            [field] => search_type
            [palanpur] => 2
            [pattukottai] => 2
            [puttur] => 2
            [universal] => 0
        )

    [7] => Array
        (
            [id] => 10000060
            [cat_name] => category_4
            [field] => search_type
            [palanpur] => 2
            [pattukottai] => 2
            [puttur] => 2
            [universal] => 0
        )

)
```

Please help to get expected output.

Answer (score 1):

You are almost at the point, you just messing up with strings/numbers.

If you want to copy exactly the old value inside the new array => id,

just

```
$newA = array();
foreach ($oldA as $k => $v) {
    $code = $v["id"]; 
    $newA["$code"] = $v;
}
```

you get a result array that contains all IDs as keys, and all the same values as values.
Notice the commas. You need to set the ID value as a string, in the new key. As far as I know, you can't set the numeric value number 1000024 of an empty array.
Imagine an array as tiles. It's like putting the tile #100024 without any tile below it!

Another thing.. you are using too much information in those arrays.
You just need 4 values:
id, city, cat, and search type.
The id will be the key, so it's unuseful to repeat it in the values

So, it's better to clean the array, while copying it:

```
$newA = array();
foreach ($oldA as $k => $v) {
    // get the ID
    $id = $v["id"]; 

    // Remove the ID, because it will be the first level key of the new array. 
    // If you want you can remove this next line, to keep the ID between the values too
    unset($v["id"]);

    foreach ($v as $k1 => $v1) {

        // Remove all numeric keys, because those are duplicated infos
        if (is_int($k1)) continue;

        // Here it is. Set the array => $id => $k1 at value $v1
        // It means that, for example, $newA['10000055']['city'] = "palanpur"
        // Notice that you need to use commas, to convert id in string. 
        // As far as I know, You can't set the numeric value of the array at position 10000025... 
        // so you need to pass it as STRING! 
        $newA["$id"][$k1] = $v1; 
    }
}
```

In this way you get an array of these types:

```
array {
  [10000024]=>
    array(3) {
        ["city"]=> "palanpur"
        ["cat_name"]=> "cat"
        ["search_tipe"]=> 0
  }
}
```

with just the minimal information needed, save memory, and make the app faster, and easier to manage...
The ID will be the key, and the sub-keys are mapped as the old array.

Comment: Gosh, you were quicker to respond than I was. Very elegant solution !

Comment: By using your code getting only single rows for each ids : `Array
(
    [10000024] => Array
        (
            [city] => puttur
            [cat_name] => category_1
            [search_type] => 0
        )
    [10000086] => Array
        (
            [city] => puttur
            [cat_name] => category_2
            [search_type] => 2
        )
    [10000059] => Array
        (
            [cat_name] => category_3
            [search_type] => 0
        )
    [10000060] => Array
        (
            [cat_name] => category_4
            [search_type] => 0
        )
)`

Comment: if i used `$newA["$id"][$k1][] = $v1;` instead of `$newA["$id"][$k1] = $v1;` then i am getting all rows but the format is not correct. getting seperate Arrays for each column like : `[10000024] => Array([city] => Array([0] => palanpur[1] => puttur)[cat_name] => Array([0] => categor_1[1] => categor_1)[search_type] => Array([0] => 0[1] => 0
))` @Daniele